# Spreading vertices out function?

Tags: vertices

I am quite new to blender and I was trying to recreate an object of a youtube video. At a certain point in the video, the guy was using a function to spread the vertices out the closest border. Does anyone recognise this function and know what the key combination is?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Blender 2.8, just follow the tutorial until the desired vertices are selected, then do the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (to activate the Bevel Tool)
- Press <kbd>V</kbd> (to make the tool act on vertices)
- Drag your mouse outwards until you get the same shape as the one in the tutorial.

Note that, whenever you've selected a tool (such as the bevel tool), some options related to its use get listed on the status bar just below the 3D Viewport.